# How to copy a row with every column except identity column (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql

My code:

```
SELECT * INTO #t FROM CTABLE WHERE CID = @cid   --get data, put into a temp table


ALTER TABLE #t
DROP COLUMN CID       -- remove primary key column CID


INSERT INTO CTABLE SELECT * FROM #t   -- insert record to table
DROP TABLE #t                                -- drop temp table
```

The error is:

```
Msg 8101,
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'CTABLE' can only 
be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.
```

And I did set

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT CTABLE OFF
GO
```

Comment: Is your table named CTABLE, or IP, or something else?

Comment: Since CID is a primary key column, I am not sure of the purpose of the `TOP (1)`. This query could only ever be handling a single row. I posted a solution where I also suggest how to do this without the #temp table... it is not clear if you've over-simplified this and there are other reasons for the #temp table.

Comment: @Aaron, Yes, CTABLE is the table name

Comment: Yes, you are right, I don't have to use top(1). Now removed.

Comment: So why are you referencing a different table in `SET IDENTITY_INSERT IP OFF`?

Comment: @Seth: In other words, is `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` actually ON or OFF for CTABLE at the time of your attempt to perform the insert?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
DECLARE 
    @cid INT,
    @o   INT,
    @t   NVARCHAR(255),
    @c   NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT
    @cid = 10,
    @t   = N'dbo.CTABLE',
    @o   = OBJECT_ID(@t);

SELECT @c = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(name), ',')
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE [object_id] = @o
    AND is_identity = 0;

SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @c + ' INTO #t 
    FROM ' + @t + ' WHERE CID = @cid;

    INSERT ' + @t + '('+ @c + ') 
    SELECT ' + @c + ' FROM #t;' 

PRINT @sql;
-- exec sp_executeSQL @sql,
--  N'@cid int',
--  @cid = @cid;
```

However it seems much easier to just build the following SQL and avoid the #temp table altogether:

```
SET @sql = 'INSERT ' + @t + '(' + @c + ') 
    SELECT ' + @c + ' FROM ' + @t + '
    WHERE CID = @cid;';

PRINT @sql;
-- exec sp_executeSQL @sql,
--  N'@cid int',
--  @cid = @cid;
```

Comment: I think you should be checking `c.is_identity` rather than `i.is_primary_key`. A column can be an identity column without being a primary key.

Comment: Yes, of course. I got tied up between the title of the question and the actual requirement. Corrected.

Comment: This should work, and I agree, the temporary table is absolutely unnecessary with this approach.

Comment: And to make this solution more universal, `CID` could be replaced with a dynamically calculated name, like `SELECT @idcolumn = QUOTENAME(name) FROM sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = @o AND is_identity = 1` maybe, and replacing later `CID` with `' + @idcolumn + '` accordingly. (Possibly beyond the scope of this question.)

Comment: @Andriy I thought about that (and I also thought about adding a check to make sure `@t` even had an identity column) but I agree with you about scope.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand  Wow.  That's impressive.  Never knew you could concatenate all the rows into a single variable like that.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT * INTO #t FROM CTABLE WHERE CID = @cid
ALTER TABLE #t
DROP COLUMN CID

INSERT CTABLE --Notice that INTO is removed here.
SELECT top(1) * FROM #t
DROP TABLE #t
```

Test Script(Tested in SQL 2005):

```
CREATE TABLE #TestIDNT
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    TITLE   VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT #TestIDNT
SELECT 'Cybenate'
```

Comment: Yes. CID is the primary key, it's the identity Column also.

Comment: +1, According to the examples for "inserting to identity column" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381.aspx it seems like that method should probably work.

Comment: `INTO` is just an optional keyword, removing it cannot have any effect.

Comment: this is a perfect answer

Comment: The "Notice that INTO is removed here" seems to be pointing out something completely irrelevant as it should work fine with the `INTO` too.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the columns:

```
INSERT INTO CTABLE 
(col2, col3, col4)
SELECT col2, col3, col4
FROM #t
```

Seems like it might be thinking you are trying to insert into the PK field since you are not explicitly defining the columns to insert into.  If Identity insert is off and you specify the non-pk columns then you shouldn't get that error.

Comment: Thanks Abe, but columns are changed very often so I have to use wild card

Comment: The columns on CTABLE are changing "very often"? Can't part of the responsibility of the person changing this schema also be responsible for changing the code that relies on the schema? Maybe that will slow them down a bit.

Comment: yeah, i'm with Aaron Bertrand on this @Seth, if that table's changing so often then it seems that something's a bit wrong with the way it's set up (unless you're just doing a lot of development and the requirements just keep changing??!)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example to dynamically build a list of columns - excluding the primary key columns - and execute the INSERT

```
declare @tablename nvarchar(100), @column nvarchar(100), @cid int, @sql nvarchar(max)
set @tablename = N'ctable'
set @cid = 1
set @sql = N''

declare example cursor for

select column_name
  from information_schema.columns
 where table_name = @tablename 
   and column_name not in (
        select column_name
          from information_schema.key_column_usage
         where constraint_name in (select constraint_name from information_schema.table_constraints)
           and table_name = @tablename
)

open example
fetch next from example into @column
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    set @sql = @sql + N'[' + @column + N'],'
    fetch next from example into @column
end
set @sql = substring(@sql, 1, len(@sql)-1)
close example
deallocate example
set @sql = N'insert into ' + @tablename + '(' + @sql + N') select top(1) ' + @sql + ' from #t'
--select @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 1):

If using SQL Server Management Studio and your problems you have too many fields to type them all out except the identity column, then right click on the table and click "Script table as" / "Select To" / "New Query Window".

This will provide a list of fields that you can copy & paste into your own query and then just remove the identity column.

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking the INSERT statement with EXEC:

```
SELECT * INTO #t FROM CTABLE WHERE CID = @cid

ALTER TABLE #t
DROP COLUMN CID

EXEC('INSERT INTO CTABLE SELECT top(1) * FROM #t')
DROP TABLE #t
```

Comment: Not sure how this helps? `INSERT (without a column list) SELECT *` will not work because `CTABLE` has an `IDENTITY` column.

Comment: @Aaron: But the IDENTITY column is not being inserted to (provided the IDENTITY_INSERT setting is OFF for the table, which it *is* by default).

Comment: @Aaron: Actually, when I posted this, I wasn't able to verify it. Now that I have verified both the OP's version and mine, I can see no problem at all, both worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, I am sure there was a time where that syntax was not valid with an `IDENTITY` column... perhaps bad memories from SQL Server 6.5?

Comment: @Aaron: Possibly. I am happier than you then, I have no memories about 6.5 at all. (I was probably still too young when it relinquished its hope of ever meeting me.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this:

```
INSERT INTO CTABLE SELECT top(1) * FROM #t
```

Because the column listings aren't the same. You've dropped the PK column from #t, so you have 1 less column in #t than in CTABLE. This is the equivalent of the following:

```
INSERT INTO CTABLE(pk, col1, col2, col3, ...) 
select top(1) col1, col2, col3, ...
from #t
```

This wouldn't work for obvious reasons. Similarly, you aren't going to be able to specify the * wildcard to do the insert if you're not inserting all of the columns. The only way to do the insert without including the PK is to specify every column. You can generate a list of columns through dynamic sql, but you'll have to specify them one way or another.

Comment: I think the first segment of your answer was true at one point, but today's SQL Server seems to be a lot smarter about ignoring the identity columns if all the other columns line up. I think the reason the column name error comes up in the OP's case is because the parser can't "see ahead" that * doesn't include the CID column. Now, I will continue to write code that explicitly specifies the column list, just in case the behavior changes again...